# Is it true that the location gotten by JavaScript is more accurate than the location gotten by IP address?

Tags: javascript, geolocation, location, ip-address, navigator

On the client side, I can get the location with Javascript by "navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition"
https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation
But I have to have the user permission for location

On the server side, I can get the location with just by the IP address, and I don't need the user permission

So Is it true that the location gotten by JavaScript is more accurate than the location gotten by IP address?

Comment: Location of an IP is not accurate at all. However getting the location from the browser is getting the location of the router you use at home (if VPN is not connected), so it is much more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML5/W3C location API works well if your device is a smartphone and the app ("user agent") is a modern browser. Discussion here: [Is W3C Geolocation API more accurate the IP geolocation for non-mobile devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68984935/is-w3c-geolocation-api-more-accurate-the-ip-geolocation-for-non-mobile-devices)

For many other use cases, IP geolocation APIs are a good bet for approximate location needs, at country and city levels.